# Why can't I just delete or format Windows 10 partition from Ubuntu without using Gparted?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu installations on my laptop. I want to uninstall or delete the Windows 10 and put back my old Windows 7 OS (I don't have the the rollback option to go back to Windows 7, only rollback to 8.1 is available, new lap came with 8.1).

So I was thinking why not just delete the Windows 10 by formatting the OS drive from Ubuntu and install Windows 7 on the formatted drive. Will this work? Please help!

And how do I delete the windows boot loader from disk? Thanks!

Comment: "Why can't I just delete or format Windows 10 partition from Ubuntu without using Gparted?" Why do you believe you can not?  And why does your title not reflect the body of the question?

Comment: I was clearly stating my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you are dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 10, it is clear that currently you are using GRUB as your bootloader that comes from Ubuntu. So, to answer this part:

```
And how do I delete the windows boot loader from disk?
```

If you delete the Windows partition, the windows bootloader will be removed without causing any issue as your current active bootloader is GRUB and you are just deleting an inactive one.

To answer this part of your question:

```
So I was thinking why not just delete the Windows 10 by formatting the OS drive 
from Ubuntu and install Windows 7 on the formatted drive. Will this work?
```

Yes, of course you can delete your Windows 10 partition from Ubuntu using `GParted` or any other similar tool (even cli ones) and then make a bootable pendrive or DVD using `Unetbootin` or `K3B` respectively. Boot from that pendrive and install windows 7 in the partition that previously contained Windows 10.

For this part:

```
Why can't I just delete or format Windows 10 partition from Ubuntu without using Gparted?
```

Yes, you can use other tools to format your Windows 10 partition apart from `Gparted` such as `fdisk` but it's much more easier to use `GParted`, then anything else currrently available. If you are wondering about GParted Live DVD, then it's not absolutely necessary. You can install GParted inside Ubuntu, by typing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

**N.B.**: If your laptop is still under warranty, then please contact your manufacturer before deleting any partition because in my country doing that voids the warranty.

**Solution to N.B.** You can back up your partitions with tools such as `Clonezilla` or the good old `dd` command to keep your warranty intact.

Comment: As me and @ktsee seem both to be in England (see there Luton town profile pick) I can confirm that removing Windows will void your warranty here too, so be careful with this downgrade.

Comment: I've already made back up of the OS. A created a recovery stick and a system image from windows, but I didn't use any third party software. And about deleting OS, I was thinking of selecting all the folders and files in the windows drive and deleting it from Ubuntu without using any special software. But I sense there is something terribly wrong with this?

Comment: @KTSree - You cannot just select all the files and folders in  your Windows partition and just delete it, it's not a pendrive. For instance, those files are not the whole of what needs to be deleted, there are many other system level files that can only be deleted if formated.

Comment: @Raphael LOL thanks man. I really had no idea. Gparted it is then!

Comment: @KTSree - Aha! Glad I could help.